# How to connect X.509 authenticated downstream device using azure python sdk version 2 to azure edge enabled gateway

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

With the now deprecated azure-iot-python-skd version 1 it was possible to connect a downstream device using X.509 authentication to a transparent iotedge enabled gateway by setting the connection string like this:
`HostName=<edge device hostname>;DeviceId=<device_id>;x509=true`

And then set the certificates by using `set_option("TrustedCerts" ...)`, `set_option("x509certificate", ...)` and `set_option("x509privatekey", ...)`

How can this be done with the new version 2 sdk?

I could not figure out how to do it using `create_from_x509_certificate(...)` or `create_from_connection_string(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

`create_from_connection_string` will not work in this case. You need to use `create_from_x509_certificate` as below:-

```
self.device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_x509_certificate(
           x509=x509, 
           hostname=hostname,
           device_id=device_id,
           server_verification_cert=root_ca_cert,
           gateway_hostname=gatewayHostname
)
```

Refer this [ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/issues/969) which is the bug fix done by MS team

Comment: This was very helpful, I couldn't find it in Msft tutorials. +1

Answer (score 0):

please try the following where you pass in your root_ca_cert as a string:

Create instance of the device client using the connection string:

device_client = IoTHubDeviceClient.create_from_connection_string(connection_string=YOUR CONNECTION STRING,server_verification_cert=YOUR ROOT CA AS STRING)

await device_client.connect()

Comment: Sadly this does not work, because the downstream device uses x509 CA authentication and not a connection string as you are suggesting.

Comment: sorry not sure I understand the issue... if authenticating via an x509 cert, you can create the device client from the cert used in the connection string. See this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/azure-iot-device/samples/async-edge-scenarios/send_message_downstream.py